# What happens when a Mac SATA drive is put in a Dell laptop?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, windows

I am planning to buy a Mac. But I see Mac uses same Intel processors as other Windows/Linux laptops. So I would like to know if I take a hard disk(say the Mac book is released before mid 2012, so the hard disk is not soldered) from the Mac book and use it in any other laptop (say a Dell) that supports the same size HDD.

Is this possible? Have any one tried. Please help me.

Comment: Yeah no. It's not that easy. One of many reasons could be drivers. But there are tons of others.

Comment: So can't I get the drivers from apple website for my system(System I mean, mac installed hard disk in a dell/asus laptop)

Comment: No you can't, the driver model of OS X and Windows are totally different. Anyway, why do you want to take the SSD from the Mac you buy and put it into a PC at all?

Comment: If I feel this is possible I will buy a cheap second hand mac book and a costly configured windows laptop, and put the mac ssd in windows laptop. May I know how the driver model of OSX is different from WIndows. Is it possible to get the drivers from existing mac book/mac center\apple website.

Comment: Buying an SSD without the Mac is probably cheaper in this case and will not lead to any driver issues. If you really want to know the difference between OS X and Windows drivers, please raise this question on StackOverflow.com

Comment: But an SSD without Mac is not my goal. I am trying to achieve Mac installed Hard disk and use it in a laptop which has cd drives and upgradable laptop.

Comment: So you want to run OS X on the Windows laptop afterwards?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about installing or using Apple operating systems on non-Apple hardware (and most other explicitly unlicensed use of product)

Comment: I've reopened this since there are answers where the parts are compatible. Clearly, just putting an Apple drive in a dell won't let the dell run OS X so we can dismiss that criteria and let a portion of this question live to explain how things work.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by "use".

1. You may access files on that drive from Windows/Linux, provided you have driver for HFS+ filesystem (Linux could have it already installed, at least in read mode, Windows driver must be downloaded separately). (i.e. the hardware is 100% compatible - and would run well if you reformatted the drive for Windows / NTFS).
2. You certainly will not get the Dell to boot OS X simply by moving the parts. OS X has very limited drivers and they are tailored strictly to Mac hardware.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. By 'use' I mean is using OS X installed on that Hard drive(that is taken from a Mac book) and use it in a dell laptop and so I will use OS X in a dell laptop that has cd drives and it is upgradable.

Comment: @user3167973 We are not the place to ask _how_ to make a Hackintosh - you can ask about that on [meta], but hopefully knowing that it's not as simple as moving a drive you can plan your efforts accordingly even if this site here won't serve to take you further down that journey.

Answer (score 0):

Ummm, last I heard a hard drive is a hard drive. And one from a Mac is the same thing as one from a PC. So YES you should be able to take a hard drive out of a Mac and put it in a PC.

The exceptions being that some Macs (Macbook Air, Retina MacBook Pro, new MacPro) use a PCI based SSD EG not SATA). Those might be problematic (not seen a PC with a similar interface for an SSD) but I have no experience with this interface, YMMV.

So as long as the interface matches and it physically fits there are no drivers to worry about on either end (Windows or MacOS). The only thing you would want to look into is enabling TRIM on a new SSD installed in a Mac. there are utilities that can do that for you a Google search away...

Answer (score 0):

Yes - all HDD in Macs since the intel transition are 100% the same parts as commodity PC parts and would be reusable in a Dell. If your mac has an SSD, your chances are much reduced as the Retina and Air lines use non-standard parts.

Apple may have some custom firmware on the drives as an OEM purchaser, but I've never seen that cause problems (where putting some PC drives with non-Apple firmware can cause issues when you put those drives in a Mac - but it seems the Apple -> Dell direction isn't likely to cause any problems).

The rest of the thread about running OS X on Dell hardware is something that won't happen without breaking the license of OS X and also some engineering effort to modify the OS X software.

Comment: Thanks you very much for reply and reopening. So is there any group(apart from Hackintosh) who have tried break the license of OS X and some engineering effort to make an original mac installed SATA disk to work in a dell laptop

Comment: Not that I'm aware of - your best bet is to check other forums and chat rooms (where we do have a chat room, we're not really a forum for general discussions) to see if anyone else can point you in that direction.

Answer (score -3):

No you can't.macbooks although they technically use the same hardware, the chips in Mac products are coded to look for specific "elements" in Mac OS. If there is no handshake between chip and OS,  Neither will operate!